# Summer Schools in Quantitative Finance

Tags: learning

I am wondering if anyone could recommend a good summer school in quantitative finance/financial econometrics?

Comment: To make the question useful for all users suggestions for summer schools anywhere in the world are welcome.

Comment: thanks, @Bob Jansen, sorry for the misunderstanding, I thought I could ask specific questions rather than general ones.

Comment: You're right that specific questions are generally better. However, a question should not be so specific that it's of limited interest to others. In this case one could ask the question for any continent. That makes it unnecessarily specific to your situation and less useful to other readers. Widening the scope should not affect the quality of the answers you receive.

Comment: Thanks @Bob Jansen I see your point. Im still learning how this works, thanks!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Stockholm Business School organises the [Summer School on Market Microstructure](http://microstructure-course.com/).

> A one-week full-time intensive course on market microstructure at PhD or advanced research master level.

Comment: The 2018 edition took place from June 25 till June 29.

Answer (score 2):

The Advanced Risk management and Portfolio Management course led by Attilio Meucci. The book it's (roughly) based on is [here](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540222132).

The classes will take place in New York in August but can also be taken online.